# I am looking for a PostgreSQL query to generate date column from date interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, epoch

I am using postgreSQL.

I would like to convert this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

where:

alarm1: dummy with value "0" (when 'created_at' is NULL) or "1" (when 'created_at' has timestamp value);
recovery_time: is timestamp
created_at: is timestamp
on_date: is date
alarm1_day_percentage: percentage of the date from 'created_at' to 'recovery_time' with alarm1=1.

For example, see from first table that id="1" has alarm1="1" on dates "2022-07-13", "2022-07-14", and "2022-07-15" (from 'created_at' to 'recovery_time'). On the date "2022-07-13" alarm1 was flagged for 8 hours (since 16:00:00.000). As a result, (see second table) for id="1" and on_date="2022-07-13", 'alarm1_day_percentage' value is "0.33" (which is 8/24). On date "2022-07-14" 'alarm1_day_percentage' value is "1.00" (which is 24/24) because alarm1 was flagged during all the date. Finally, on date "2022-07-15" 'alarm1_day_percentage' value is "0.42" (which is 10/24) because alarm1 was flagged for 10 hours (until 10:00:00.000).

Also, observe that whenever 'recovery_time' or 'created_at' is NULL, the associated 'id' should not go into the second table.

I am using postgresql. Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Best,

[n]

Comment: Yes, first table id is the same as in second table id.

Comment: Look at `generate_series()`

Comment: What is did in the DBFIDDLE was using a "common table expression" (CTE), but in PostgreSQL it might be easier to use a `generate_series`, and use that, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cfdad9afcd6e642b1f8b9b77b412b438)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=78eb202b6bd9d7b3ad56a0563bbb6d03), and try to make it into a complete solution:

```
-- 
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
   SELECT CAST(MIN(CAST(created_at AS DATE)) AS TIMESTAMP) d FROM table1
   
   UNION ALL
   
   SELECT d+INTERVAL '1 DAY' 
   FROM dates
   WHERE d <= (SELECT MAX(recovery_time) FROM table1))
SELECT 
   d.d, 
   id,
   created_at,
   CASE WHEN CAST(created_at as DATE) != CAST(d.d as DATE)
        THEN d.d 
        ELSE created_at END as from_dt,
   CASE WHEN CAST(recovery_time as DATE) != CAST(d.d as DATE)
        THEN d.d + (CAST('23:59:59' as TIME))
        ELSE recovery_time END as to_dt
FROM dates d
INNER JOIN table1 t ON (NOT(t.created_at is null and t.recovery_time is null) 
                      and CAST(t.created_at AS DATE) <= d.d and CAST(t.recovery_time AS DATE) >= d.d)
ORDER BY d.d, t.id;
```

output:

| d | id | created_at | from_dt | to_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 4 | 2022-05-01 02:00:00 | 2022-05-01 02:00:00 | 2022-05-01 03:00:00 |
| 2022-07-13 00:00:00 | 1 | 2022-07-13 16:00:00 | 2022-07-13 16:00:00 | 2022-07-13 23:59:59 |
| 2022-07-14 00:00:00 | 1 | 2022-07-13 16:00:00 | 2022-07-14 00:00:00 | 2022-07-14 23:59:59 |
| 2022-07-15 00:00:00 | 1 | 2022-07-13 16:00:00 | 2022-07-15 00:00:00 | 2022-07-15 10:00:00 |

This show all day that an alarm was 'active'.  I think it's a nice part to get you started, (and I know it's not a complete answer!).